# How to take to two columns of data, perform a calculation and create a new column with that data

Tags: r

I am not sure if the way I hardcoded this table is the best way of doing it. But anyways, rn I am trying to take the total points column and dividing it by the time needed to get the points per minute then create a new column for that calculation but I can't seem to make it work.

```
table <- data.frame(list(Question=c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4" , "Q5" , "Q6" , "Q7" , "Q8", "Q9"), 
                        Total_Points=c("21","5","10","14","5","5","10","5","5"), Time_needed=c("24","7","15","12","4","3","10","5","6")))
table <- transform(table, Points_per_min = table$Total_Points / table$Time_needed)
```

Gives me an error "Warning message:
In Ops.factor(table$Total_Points, table$Time_needed) :
  ‘/’ not meaningful for factors"

Thanks so much for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The warning is informative here, which you can see by examining the `str()` of `table`. It tells you that all your variables are of type factor. [Check here](https://www.statmethods.net/input/datatypes.html) for a quick intro on different data types.

Convert your data to numeric then do your math:

```r
table <- data.frame(list(Question=c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4" , "Q5" , "Q6" , "Q7" , "Q8", "Q9"), 
                         Total_Points=c("21","5","10","14","5","5","10","5","5"), Time_needed=c("24","7","15","12","4","3","10","5","6")))
str(table)
#> 'data.frame':    9 obs. of  3 variables:
#>  $ Question    : Factor w/ 9 levels "Q1","Q2","Q3",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
#>  $ Total_Points: Factor w/ 4 levels "10","14","21",..: 3 4 1 2 4 4 1 4 4
#>  $ Time_needed : Factor w/ 9 levels "10","12","15",..: 4 9 3 2 6 5 1 7 8
table$Total_Points <- as.numeric(as.character(table$Total_Points))
table$Time_needed <- as.numeric(as.character(table$Time_needed))
table$Points_per_min <- table$Total_Points / table$Time_needed
table
#>   Question Total_Points Time_needed Points_per_min
#> 1       Q1           21          24      0.8750000
#> 2       Q2            5           7      0.7142857
#> 3       Q3           10          15      0.6666667
#> 4       Q4           14          12      1.1666667
#> 5       Q5            5           4      1.2500000
#> 6       Q6            5           3      1.6666667
#> 7       Q7           10          10      1.0000000
#> 8       Q8            5           5      1.0000000
#> 9       Q9            5           6      0.8333333
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

[@Chase](https://stackoverflow.com/users/415635/chase) already explained why you were not able to create a new column before, but in case you wanted a solution involving fewer lines of code, you can use the `dplyr` package (I'm using `dplyr` version 0.7.6).

As [@Ozgur Yigit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6473971/ozgur-yigit) mentioned, you do not need to pass in your data as a list.  You can actually just pass in each column as an argument for `data.frame(...)`.

EDITED

```
library(dplyr)

table <- data.frame(Question = c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4" , "Q5" , "Q6" , "Q7" , "Q8", "Q9"), 
                    Total_Points = c("21","5","10","14","5","5","10","5","5"), 
                    Time_needed = c("24","7","15","12","4","3","10","5","6"))
table %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(Total_Points, Time_needed), 
            funs(as.numeric(as.character(.)))) %>% # converts the `Total_Points` and `Time_needed` cols to character first (b/c factors coded as integers under the hood) then to numeric
  mutate(Points_per_min = Total_Points / Time_needed)
```

For more information on `mutate()`: https://r4ds.had.co.nz/transform.html#add-new-variables-with-mutate

PS Apologies if my response is unhelpful or outside the scope of SO responses.  I am still learning how to write answers on SO.

Comment: this doesn't work. I just realised - factors are encoded as numbers, hence if you re-class to numeric before first re-classing to character, you'll get the wrong result. it needs to reclassify `as.character` then `as.numeric`

Comment: Thanks @nycrefugee!  You're totally right.  I edited my response

Answer (score 0):

you can use `tidyverse` but only need one `mutate` statement - little different from the other answerer:

```
table2 <- table %>%
     mutate(Total_Points = as.numeric(as.character(Total_Points)),
     Time_needed  = as.numeric(as.character(Time_needed)),
     Points_per_min = Total_Points / Time_needed)

  Question Total_Points Time_needed Points_per_min
1       Q1           21          24      0.8750000
2       Q2            5           7      0.7142857
3       Q3           10          15      0.6666667
4       Q4           14          12      1.1666667
5       Q5            5           4      1.2500000
6       Q6            5           3      1.6666667
7       Q7           10          10      1.0000000
8       Q8            5           5      1.0000000
9       Q9            5           6      0.8333333
```